# How to create a record automatically when a checkbox is set to true in an object

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, process-builder, development-mode

I have an object `Product stock`, which has a checkbox on it called `reorder point`. Whenever a Product stock record has the `reorder point` checkbox checked we send out an email notification. But we would like to have it also create a new `parts request`. `Parts request` is another object. It has the below fields.

Parts Request
Line Status
Request Part
Request Qty
Date Required
Additional Information
Use Price From Pricebook
Unit Price
Total Line Price

Shipment/Receipt Information
Qty Shipment Initiated      Qty Received
Qty Shipped         Date Received
Date Shipped        Posted To Inventory
Description
Optional Part #
Delivery Location
Work Order

If some has solution for this please let me know asap
Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to be more clear on what you are asking? Are you looking for help with a trigger, do you have any code you can share?

Comment: Processbuilder!

Comment: Yes I want Process builder login.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for the Process Builder! Take some time to check out the following links to learn a little bit more about the Process Builder and how to use it!

[Intro to Process Builder (Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxRAnpDtaPk)

[Process Builder - Salesforce Overview](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Process_Builder)

[Create a new Process - Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/project/quickstart-process-builder/quickstart-process-builder1)